# How to find an element in a list based on a condition and return some data associated with that element in Scala

Tags: scala

I am having a bit of hard time thinking in Scala and I keep going back to the imperative model style of thinking. What Scala pattern can I use to implement in the Scala way the following rough pseudocode:

```
for (item in list)
{
  val result = some_func(item) // result is a pair (Boolean, some data)
  if (result._1)
    return result
}
return (false, null)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `map` to apply the function, then `find` to find a mapped value for which `_1 == true`, which gives an `Option`, and then use `getOrElse` to return a default value.

```
def perform[A, B](list: List[A])(fun: A => (Boolean, B)): (Boolean, B) =
  list.map(fun).find(_._1).getOrElse((false, null.asInstanceOf[B]))
```

The disadvantage is that `map` will apply `fun` to *all* elements, whereas you would prefer to abort on the first element for which `_1 == true`:

```
val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

perform(xs) { x =>
  println(s"Testing $x")
  (x % 2 == 0, x / 2)
}
```

> ```
> Testing 1
> Testing 2
> Testing 3
> Testing 4
> res0: (Boolean, Int) = (true,1)
> ```

One possibility is to use an iterator:

```
def perform[A, B](list: List[A])(fun: A => (Boolean, B)): (Boolean, B) =
  list.iterator.map(fun).find(_._1).getOrElse((false, null.asInstanceOf[B]))
```

> ```
> Testing 1
> Testing 2
> res1: (Boolean, Int) = (true,1)
> ```

---

Also, consider returning an `Option[B]` instead of `(Boolean, B)`, that way you avoid the ugliness of `null` and it's safer to handle on the return side:

```
def perform[A, B](list: List[A])(fun: A => (Boolean, B)): Option[B] =
  list.iterator.map(fun).collectFirst { case (true, res) => res }
```

---

Regarding iterator vs view:

- http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/stream-view-iterator.html
- [Stream vs Views vs Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159000/stream-vs-views-vs-iterators)
- [What is the difference between the methods iterator and view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798043/what-is-the-difference-between-the-methods-iterator-and-view)

I find it always easier to keep track of iterators as long as they offer the methods required. I also think the view mechanism will be reworked in future collections.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post: [Finding elements in a scala list and also know which predicate has been satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175873/finding-elements-in-a-scala-list-and-also-know-which-predicate-has-been-satisfie) I came up with this:

```
list.view.map(el => (el, some_func(el))).find(t => t._2._1)
```